# Resultado errado ao fazer o calculo do IMC

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um exercício com a linguagem C para calcular o IMC, não dá nenhum erro no compilador mas o resultado sai tudo errado, eu já olhei o código e não acho o erro de jeito nenhum.

O código é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"PORTUGUESE");
    printf("Claculo de imc\n");
    //variaveis peso e altura
    double peso;
    double altura;
    printf("Por favor digite seu peso: ");
    scanf("%f",&peso);
    printf("por favor digite sua altura: ");
    scanf("%f",&altura);



  double imc;
  imc = peso/(altura *altura );
  printf("Seu imc é de %.2f",imc);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mude os formatos do printf de `f` pra `lf` e use ponto ao invés de virgula quando for informar o peso/altura. Fiz isso e funcionou aqui.

Comment: @Leonardo do scanf, não? :-)

Comment: Sim, ambos (printf e scanf).

Comment: Ou mudar as variáveis para float, mas ai perde em precisão.

Comment: Vc tem q considerar o sexo da pessoa tbm e fazer o ajuste na formula.

Comment: Uma micro optimização seria declarar todas as variáveis em uma linha só

Comment: @MarceloBoni o que não fará diferença alguma. Eu acho que já tem uma resposta para isto, mas como não acho a duplicata, se ninguém achar quem vai responder? Leonardo? Eu nem questionei outros pequenos problemas no código que é mais estilo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema era que você estava utilizando o formato `%f` ao invés do `%lf`, que é o correto para se utilizar com o `double`. Basta alterar para `%lf` em ambos `printf` e `scanf`.

No `printf` é opcional, porém é recomendado.

Código alterado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"PORTUGUESE");
    printf("Claculo de imc\n");
    //variaveis peso e altura
    double peso;
    double altura;
    printf("Por favor digite seu peso: ");
    scanf("%lf",&peso);
    printf("por favor digite sua altura: ");
    scanf("%lf",&altura);

    double imc;
    imc = peso/(altura *altura );
    printf("Seu imc é de %.2lf",imc);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Em complemento ao que foi dito acima, tome cuidado com `setlocale(LC_ALL,"PORTUGUESE");`. Se a linguagem for setada como portugues então as casas decimais dos números de ponto flutuante serão represantadas por vírgula, enquanto em inglês serão representados por ponto.

Comment: O que achei estranho foi que mesmo com este `setlocale`, caso você coloque um número com vírgula ao invés de ponto o `scanf` lê apenas o número antes da vírgula. Não sei se isso é normal pois não tenho muita experiência em C/C++.

Comment: Confesso que não tive esse problema. Aqui rodou de boas

Comment: É estranho. Compilei usando o gcc 4.8.4. Olhe: http://i.imgur.com/XocANx3.png

Comment: na segunda tentiva, como estava setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE"); ?

Comment: Ambos são os mesmos, eu simplesmente coloquei o número com virgula no primeiro e ponto no segundo (ali na altura).